# Setting Excel gridlines VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-charts

I have a specific issue with setting the X-axis (radial) gridlines in an Excel chart from a VB.Net application. I'm wanting to set the colour.

These are some things I have tried based on suggested solutions here and elsewhere. Even where a property is recognised, there is no visible effect in the chart.

```
'Sets the style of the radial gridlines as light grey, only none of this has any affect
With myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridlines.Format.Line
  .Visible = True
  .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(240, 240, 240)
  .Weight = 0.5
End With

'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridLines.Border.ColorIndex = RGB(240, 240, 240) 'No effect
'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridLines.LineColor = RGB(240, 240, 240) 'LineColor not recognised property
'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).LineColor = RGB(240, 240, 240) 'LineColor not recognised property
'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGrid.LineColor = RGB(240, 240, 240) 'MajorGrid Not recognised property
'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridLines.Color = RGB(240, 240, 240) 'Not recognised property
'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).GridLines.Color = RGB(240, 240, 240) 'Not recognised property
'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Color = RGB(240, 240, 240) 'Color not recognised property
'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridLines.LineColor.RGB = RGB(240, 240, 240) 'LineColor not recognised property

myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridLines.Format.Line.Visible = False 'No effect. Suggested google fix in VBA to make
myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridLines.Format.Line.Visible = True

myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(240, 240, 240) 'No effect
myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Color.Red 'No effect

myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridLines.border.color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed 'No effect
'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Color.RGB = Color.Red 'Color not recognised property



'This works as expected, so has to be a property of MajorGridlines....
'myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(1).MajorGridLines.Delete()
```

This only appears to be an issue with the X-Axis, the Y-Axis (polar lines) work just fine.

```
'Sets the style of the polar gridlines as light grey.
With myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(2).MajorGridlines.Format.Line
  .Visible = True
  .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(230, 230, 230)
End With
```

[Example of final chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98NcJ.png)

You can see in the final chart (link attached) that I am almost there, but the final tweak required by my end user is to tone down the radial lines from the default.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have to identify the gridlines as follows:

```
myStellarChart.Chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).Format.Line
```

Finished chart:

[image: Finished chart]